# Sliding Menu On Android

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer, android-sliding

I want to create app with below feature

[image]

in first image I have vertical menu inside left,when slide, this ribbon open full 
[ second picture ]

**how can I develop this app ? what is the best way for create this design?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [DrawerLayerLayout](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which can contain any UI Element you want it to be. 
Any Drawerlayout which covers the ActionBar is third party, there a some good one out there like the jfeinstein lib.